# {{/depend}} on shipping and billing

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, shipping-address, billing-address

[image]

there is a **{{/depend}}** what is the problem of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming from the HTML address template, you find in *System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Address Templates*

It has a format like this:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
```

Where `{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}` means, that the prefix (and a space) are only shown if "prefix" is not empty.

In your case the template was edited (maybe to remove the prefix or the middlename) but a single `{{/depend}}` is still there, where the corresponding `{{depend}}` was removed.

**Solution:** Find it and remove it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your email template HTML, is there proper tags are start and close?

```
{{depend}}....{{/depend}}
```